# what's the difference between custom cell class vs files owner

Tags: ios

In the official developer guide(and other guides like it), it mentions that you need to set the custom class property of a cell in order to make IBOutlet connections. This custom class is simply an objective c class with IBOutlet markers on @properties. What I'm struggling to understand is how this custom class property for a cell differs from files owner of a XIB. From my experimentation, I can leave files owner blank and all of the connections still work as long as the custom class is set on the cell(I click on the cell and go to "identity inspector" and set the custom class of the cell). I thought that a files owner is the only thing the UI views can interact with.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

ctrl+f "To use outlets for the custom cell content" to get to the spot in the docs.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same question and experimented around a bit. From what I can see, the `Custom Class` attribute is applicable for every view in your `XIB`. Ie if you have a `XIB` with a UI design that has several UI objects, each can have a separate custom class. The custom class, must also be a subclass of the parent class of the UIView object you have in you `XIB`. For example for a `cell` the custom class must be a `UITableViewCell`.

The `File Owner` on the other hand is only one and for the entire `XIB`. It can be **ANY** class (from what I can see). 
In my case as an example,  I have `XIB` with custom `UITableViewCell` with a text field and some labels. I use the cell as the Header View of a table (i.e. in a `UITableView` object).

In my case I did **NOT** create a custom class for my `XIB`. I just made the cell's file owner my `UITableViewController` (which is manage my tableview), and connected my textfield and labels to properties in the `UITableViewController` class. This works for me as I only ever have **ONE** instance my custom `TableViewCell` (its the header of the entire table, and there is only one header).

Answer (score 0):

A file's owner is just a convenient way provided by Interface Builder to refer to a runtime instantiated object, which is usually the `UIViewController` associated with the main view.

That said, you can refer to as many other objects you want, especially if you have a hierarchy of views or view controllers.